# no such column error when trying to retrieve data in raw() Query in Django

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-queryset

I have the following classes in my `models.py`

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField('User Name', null=False, max_length = 50)
    password = models.CharField('User Password', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Image")
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(Users, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo_History(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/results")
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    photo_id = models.ForeignKey(Photo, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Table Structure is as follows,

For the **Users** Class,

| username | password |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |
| dec | 123 |
| john | 123 |

For the **Photo** Class,

| id | name | uploader (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | abc |
| 2 | second | abc |
| 3 | third | dec |

For the **Photo History** Class,

| image | upload_time | photo_id (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| img | 12-01-2022 | 1 |
| img | 12-03-2022 | 1 |
| img | 12-04-2022 | 3 |
| img | 12-05-2022 | 2 |

What I am trying to access is, a user is logged in. I need to get the Photo History Objects along with the "name" from the `Photo` model of the user who's currently logged in.

So, let's say if the user **abc** is logged in, then it should display the following Results,

| name | img | upload_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | img | 12-01-2022 |
| first | img | 12-03-2022 |
| second | img | 12-05-2022 |

I tried to search a way to write a command using `filter` function to get this but I couldn't find any results that showed how you can get data from two different tables in a single query. And instead, people mentioned I should be using `raw()` query.

So I used the raw query which I believe is totally fine, but I am getting a weird error (which you get if you haven't done in your migrations, but my migrations were done long ago and **the column for which it is showing error, I can easily retrieve data from it in other queries**)

This is the function that I have with the query,

```
def history(request):
    if request.session.has_key('is_logged'):
        current_user_id= request.session['user_id']
        q = "select p.name, h.image, h.upload_time from firstApp_Photo_History h, firstApp_Photo p where p.uploader=%s;"
        photos = Photo_History.objects.raw(q, [str(Users.objects.filter(username=current_user_id)[0])])
        
        print("Photos: ", photos)
        for p in photos:
            print(p.name)
            print(p.username)
            print(p.upload_time)
        return render(request, 'history.html', {'ID':current_user_id, 'photos':photos})
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

When I try to run this, I get an error that

```
no such column: p.uploader
```

Can anyone tell me what's the issue and how can I resolve this?

Here's the Complete Error,

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Photos:  <RawQuerySet: select p.name, h.image, h.upload_time from firstApp_Photo_History h, firstApp_Photo p where p.uploader=hassan;>
Internal Server Error: /history
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: p.uploader

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\imageNetProject\firstApp\views.py", line 67, in history
    for p in photos:
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1514, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1501, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1524, in iterator
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 136, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, params)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\Hassan\Semester 8\Research\Example2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: p.uploader
[24/Apr/2022 04:14:04] "GET /history HTTP/1.1" 500 128502
```

Comment: joins are around for 30 Years, so why not use them

Comment: please provide the table structure of tables used in the query

Comment: @nbk I don't see it being an issue of using joins or not. Regardless, even if I use joins, the issue remains the same. It is failing to access the uploader attribute

Comment: @NishantGupta I have provided the Classes structure, and have added the table structure as well for the expected results.

Comment: Your query is very bad you make a **cross join without provide a as linking sturcture inthe where clause, so make a join in sqllite and run your query, we have a structure for phot but notg for firstApp_Photo  so run first a select for firstApp_Photo  and see which columns it has

Comment: @nbk firstApp is the name of `Django App`. As per the documentation, when we are using `raw` query, we have to use the name of the Django App with the Table Name, which is why `firstApp_Photo` is used. It refers to the same Photo structure. I have tried to use join as well for same purpose but it has given me the same error.

Comment: @HassanAshas what i think the error is because of  'where p.uploader=hassan' since after translation of raw query it is not putting "hassan" in between single quotes.

Comment: that is why you should make a `SELECT * FROM firstApp_Photo`to drr what you have. And for the final time , you qury is a bad  as can get, it costs zo much tme and space to do a simple task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the Django Documentation, I found that Django adds a **`_id`** at the end of foreign key name.

Hence, I was able to solve my issue by changing `p.uploader` to `p.uploader_id`. A weird issue but this is how the Django models work.

The Final Query was,

```
q = "select h.id, p.name, h.image, h.upload_time from firstApp_Photo_History h, firstApp_Photo p where p.uploader_id=%s;"
```